# Variable equals to the returned value of another function i another file

Tags: python

I have this line here:

```
sys_status = status().read()
```

This should call the imported class/function:

```
class status(self):
 def read(self):
    with open("/home/pi/project/mytext.txt", "r+") as fo:
      fo.seek(0, 0)
      sys_status = fo.read(1)
    fo.closed
    return status
```

The result on the sys_status variable should be the readable text on the textfile, but instead when I call this:

```
sys_status = status().read()
print "Status:", sys_status
```

The result is: Status: keypaddweb.status

Whats wrong with my code?

Comment: Note that the code in parenthesis after a class name is a list of the base classes that your class inherits from.  Why are you inheriting from `self`?  Is `self` the name of a base class?  If so, it should be renamed to something more descriptive.  Otherwise, you should be having your class inherit from `object` so that it is a [new-style class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867/old-style-and-new-style-classes-in-python).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have an incorrect return statement in your `read` function - you mean to `return sys_status` and not `return status`, which will just print details about class `status`.

Also, your class definition is incorrect, either do

```
class status():
    def read(self):
    ...
```

or do

```
class status(object):
    def read(self):
    ...
```

Comment: Oh my god! I need a break ASAP, my brain stopped working! Thanks MU!

Comment: Sure, theres a time limit. I wont forget!